# Regex of the string (URI)

Tags: regex

I'd like to put together REGEX for the string:

```
/maps/basic/5/16/12.png?key=xxx
```

What I am trying to achieve here is, that my condition will be TRUE IF the string (URI) will contain 3 numbers after 2 words:

```
/word/word/number/number/number*
```

Comment: Should it return true if there are more than 3 numbers after two words? what if there are three numbers after two or more words?

Comment: @anotherGatsby yes, even if there are more than 3 numbers it should return true. At the beginning has to be only 2 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
^(\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)(\S.*)$
```

The result of your example would be:

1. Group 1 match: `/maps/basic/5/16/12`
2. Group 2 match, the rest of the string: `.png?key=xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+.*


^                 mathes the beginning of the string
\/[a-zA-Z]+       matches the first word
\/[a-zA-Z]+       matches the second word
\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+   matches the three numbers
.*                matches anything after the numbers
```

This matches the url only if it begins with two words and is followed by three (or more ) words with anything after that.

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/mjWNUb/1